# How to retriew data of Employee model in users registration form in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am creating an ERP app using Django. I have the Employee model which holds the master data of the employee. Employees must register themselves before using the app. I have created a page where the employee enters his employee number and if an employee exists in the database he/she can register himself/herself to the app.
In my registration form, I want to retrieve the information of the employee form employee model whose Employee Number is checked. how to do that? how can I pass the information of the employee to the registration form? please help

Answer (score 0):

for example if you want to retrive the username request.user.username

Answer (score 0):

From what you have written i am able to get a little bit about your problem. I think you have problem after the employee check number is verified and you want to know that how can employee can enter his/her own data to the database. You can do a simple thing by creating a new model employee details and in that model you can enter the employee details and from that you can use **foreign key** to connect the two models.

Comment: Thnaks for answering.